requests.get doesn't work for one part of the website but it does work in others
As I've stated in the title, when trying to scrape jlptsensei.com to make notes I'm running into problems in certain pages of the website, that as far as I can see do not differ from the pages that do work.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-kanji/%e6%97%a5-nichi-jitsu-day-sun/'
result = requests.get(url)
doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')

title = doc.find(class_='eng-definition p-lg')

print(title)
print('\n')

url = 'https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-kanji/%e4%bc%9a-kai-au-meet/'
result = requests.get(url)
doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')

title = doc.find(clas_='eng-definition p-lg')

print(title)

Below is the response that I get from each "print(title)" and the first one works perfectly fine but the second returns None because "requests.get(url)" returns only some javascript code as far as I can see.

day, sun, Japan, counter for days
None

I'm not sure what the problem is, since I try this exact code on 100 pages of jlptsensei.com and it works on about 90% of those, can anyone please explain to me what goes wrong in 10% of the cases? I've already tried putting headers into requests.get but it didn't help. Thank you very much!

You have clas_ as parameter name, should be class_:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = [
    "https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-kanji/%e6%97%a5-nichi-jitsu-day-sun/",
    "https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-kanji/%e4%bc%9a-kai-au-meet/",
]

for url in urls:
    result = requests.get(url)
    doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
    title = doc.find(class_="eng-definition p-lg")
    print(title)

Prints:
<p class="eng-definition p-lg">day, sun, Japan, counter for days</p>
<p class="eng-definition p-lg">meeting; meet</p>


EDIT: The page probably has some protection against fast scraping so add sleep between the requests:
import time

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = [
    "https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-kanji/%e6%97%a5-nichi-jitsu-day-sun/",
    "https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-kanji/%e4%bc%9a-kai-au-meet/",
    "https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-kanji/%e4%ba%8c-ni-futatsu-two-2/",
]

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:125.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/125.0"
}

with requests.session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    for url in urls:
        result = s.get(url)
        doc = BeautifulSoup(result.content, "html.parser")
        title = doc.find(class_="eng-definition p-lg")
        print(title)
        time.sleep(1)

Prints:
<p class="eng-definition p-lg">day, sun, Japan, counter for days</p>
<p class="eng-definition p-lg">meeting; meet</p>
<p class="eng-definition p-lg">two, 2</p>


Oh, you're definitely right about that but to be honest, this was just an isolated "testing code", and now it doesn't work with this link: https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-kanji/%e4%ba%8c-ni-futatsu-two-2/
In my actual code there is a for loop that cycles through each link from https://jlptsensei.com/kanji-list-ordered-by-frequency-of-use/
and the loop works on about 90% of links as it's stated in the post. You were right about the typo and now it works with that specific link, but if I paste the problematic link into this code it doesn't work now either.

@fur1osa The page has some protection against fast scraping so you can try to add time.sleep between the requests and/or try to load the page again if you've been served captcha page.

I've tried using time.sleep() even with 5 seconds of delay and there seems to be no difference, some pages still don't provide sufficient results.
Also can you please provide some help detecting/bypassing captcha pages?
I'm a bit new to stackoverflow, so I'm not sure how I can provide my code in a comment, but I pretty much used the same code you provided me, to make sure there are no errors from my part, with a bit of code at the start to gather all 100 links to parse through
